# Why do defunct links to the old astronomy site still format correctly into a linked title?

Tags: bug, site-salvage

[This question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/broken-internal-link) pointed out that there are still a number of links to posts on the old Astronomy SE site kicking around, and that they mostly redirect to new, unrelated questions and answers in the new Astronomy site. I feel those links *should* have been automatically edited at the time of the migration, but it doesn't really matter, since a [quick query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/628571/links-to-the-old-astronomy-se-site) turns up ~30 or so sites, which can easily be edited manually.

I do find one thing pretty weird, though: when those links are posted as a raw URL, they still format correctly, for some reason. As an example, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/what-is-the-fate-of-the-asteroid-belt), which [until recently](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/25789/revisions) contained the explicit URL

```
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/861/why-did-the-asteroid-belt-between-mars-and-jupiter-form-as-it-did
```

which is a [broken link](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/861/why-did-the-asteroid-belt-between-mars-and-jupiter-form-as-it-did) (i.e. should point [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/why-did-the-asteroid-belt-between-mars-and-jupiter-form-as-it-did)) but nevertheless still formats correctly into a full title with the old link.

> [image]

This feels weirdly buggy to me, though of course the real bug is that the URLs were not auto-updated to begin with.

Comment: No repro, posting the raw link in a new answer does not format it. I think the post text was simply formatted into the correctly titled link *once* when the old astronomy.SE still existed and the post not edited since then.

Comment: Indeed, it's no-repro on newly posted links, but consider e.g. [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26324) (with the explicit url in its [revision history](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/26324/revisions)). (Don't edit it yet, though, or it reverts.)

Comment: Yeah, so this shows the source for a post is only parsed once per revision into what's displayed on the site, no?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't claim to have uncovered a big mistery ;-), I just thought it was interesting enough.